# Creating a dynamic product ad's ad set

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the v2.3 php ads sdk to try to create a ad set for a dynamic product ad, but I'm getting a weird error: Your audience must be using the same product set ID as specified in Ad Set's promoted object.

Full error:

```
[message] => An unknown error occurred
[type] => FacebookApiException
[code] => 1
[error_subcode] => 1487852
[is_transient] => 
[error_user_title] => Product Set Mismatch
[error_user_msg] => Your audience must be using the same product set ID as specified in Ad Set's promoted object.
```

My code:

```
Api::init($this->app_id, $this->app_secret, $this->access_token);

$targeting = new TargetingSpecs();
$targeting->{TargetingSpecsFields::GEO_LOCATIONS} = array('countries' => array('US'));
$targeting->{TargetingSpecsFields::CUSTOM_AUDIENCES} = array("id" => '<CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID>');

$this->adSet = new AdSet(null, '<act_AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');
$this->adSet->setData(array(
    AdSetFields::NAME => 'Fitbit Surge',
    AdSetFields::BID_TYPE => BidTypes::BID_TYPE_CPC,
    AdSetFields::BID_INFO => array(BidInfoFields::CLICKS => 150),
    AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET => 2000,
    AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_GROUP_ID => '<CAMPAIGN_GROUP_ID>',
    AdSetFields::TARGETING => $targeting,
    AdsetFields::PROMOTED_OBJECT => array('product_set_id' =>
                                          "<PRODUCT_SET_ID>")
    ));

$this->adSet->save();
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear on the error. Are you sure that the PRODUCT_SET_ID is same as the one on the CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID?

Comment: The custom audience is built up from website traffic so I'm not sure why it has to be tied to a product set (except for the fact that the tracking pixel sends a product id in it's events) or even where to add a product set to the custom audience.

Comment: Can you please create a bug report on developers.facebook.com/bugs and someone can look into this in more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently, you cannot use custom_audiences without product_audience_specs. So I added

```
   "product_audience_specs":[
      {
         "product_set_id":"<MY_PRODUCT_SET_ID>",
         "inclusions":[
            {
               "retention_seconds":864000,
               "rule":{
                  "event":{
                     "eq":"ViewContent"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "retention_seconds":864000,
               "rule":{
                  "event":{
                     "eq":"AddToCart"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "exclusions":[
            {
               "retention_seconds":864000,
               "rule":{
                  "event":{
                     "eq":"Purchase"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

to my targeting JSON and it worked :)